# Dynmically cast a object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Can someone explain why this code doesnt work and throw error:incompatible type :Object cannot be converted to aaa

```
class aaa {}

class bbb extends aaa {

}

class psp {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

        bbb b = new bbb();

        Object object = b;
        Class clazz = aaa.class;
       //aaa a=clazz.cast(b); doesnot work
      //aaa a=Class.forName("aaa").cast(object); doesnt work
     //aaa a=Class.forName("aaa").cast(b);doesnt work
        aaa a = (aaa) object;
        a = (aaa) aa;
        a = aaa.class.cast(b);

 }
}
```

PS:I'm talking about commented code

Comment: `Class clazz` is a raw type. Use `Class<aaa> clazz`.

Comment: Can someone tell me why my question is downvoted?

Comment: @TarunRawat what do you even mean by dynamically casting it? Casting does nothing in java, it is only an explicit check of type. You can't then check if something is of type that you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems easy to correct:

Declare `clazz` as `Class<aaa>` to eliminate the need to cast `clazz.cast(b)` to `aaa`:

```
Class<aaa> clazz = aaa.class;

aaa a = clazz.cast(b); //works
```

`Class.forName` returns `Class<?>`, so you need to explicitly cast:

```
aaa a1 = (aaa) Class.forName("aaa").cast(object);
aaa a2 = (aaa) Class.forName("aaa").cast(b);
```

Comment: I want to dynamically cast it. what should i do ?

Comment: @TarunRawat what do you even mean by dynamically casting it? Casting does nothing in java, it is only an explicit check of type. You can't then check if something is of type that you don't know.

Comment: You can use `aaa a = Class.forName("aaa").asSubClass(aaa.class).cast(b);` It first checks that the dynamically loaded class is compatible with `aaa`. Then, it allows type safe `cast`, as instances of the dynamically loaded class are proven to be instances of `aaa` as well.